# Viewing Docker Compose web app on server outside host machine (the host is OSX)

Tags: macos, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

My computer is OSX. I'm logged into an ssh connection (Ubuntu), and from there I'm ssh'ed into an OpenStack instance of Ubuntu 14.04. From this OpenStack instance I've been following a Docker-Compose tutorial from the Docker docs : https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

I'm on Step 4, and I'm successfully running a server that is running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/

However, I don't know how to view a GUI Google Chrome browser from my Macbook. Because whenever I go to http://0.0.0.0:5000/ it says server not found, which makes sense because it's not on my computer.

I read something about port forwarding, but I'm not sure that's right here. I'm fairly new, so please help!

Also, is this the right way to use an OpenStack machine? That you use your computer's web browser to view the web app?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Turns out on OpenStack, you need to create a security group and then add it to your instance. When you create a security group, you can add a port that you want to provide public access to. And then you can view the web app on any computer by typing in your floating IP on OpenStack, colon separated by the public port address.